# How can I variably stress test a server with Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, load-testing, stress-testing

I need to stress test a group of servers but is there a way to stress test a normal Ubuntu instance that doesn't just whack the CPU percentage up to 100%. Something that holds the CPU at 60% for example or does variable stress tests that keep the CPU fluctuating? I just want something simple that doesn't just whack the CPU up to 100% right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For specifying the load on cpu You could use `stress-ng`. It has an option to so that one can specify 0 for the number of stressor processes to match the number of on-line CPUs, so to load each cpu at say 40% You can do:

```
stress-ng -c 0 -l 40
```

As for testing a group of server there are various solutions for example You could use **Siege**.